# Devices cannot connect to my laptop over lan

Tags: windows-10, router, audio, android, audio-streaming

I am currently trying to stream audio from my Windows 10 laptop and my Android phone. I have tried multiple programs such as VLC, Soundwire and SWYH (Stream What You Hear) however they all fail to connect. I then attempted to connect to TeamViewer while exclusively accepting LAN connections which still failed. Yes, I have checked the firewall and played with that which did not work.

I am a beginner, so any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

(VLC, I have tried over both http and RTP / MPEG transport stream, Soundwire seems to be a direct connection since I am only provided with the internal ip of the broadcasting computer as the server address and I have only tried SWYH over http.)

Thanks,
Jamanak

Comment: If both are WiFi devices, make sure the access point allows communications between WiFi clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try Voicemeeter virtual audio mixer... with VBAN features, it can send stream to your mobile device (with VBAN-Receptor application - lite version is free for test).